# F#: Extract the same length overlapping contiguous sublists from a list

Tags: list, f#

In F# have an N elements long list and I would like to extract all possible M elements long overlapping contiguous sublists (M < N), e.g.:

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

produces

```
[[1; 2; 3]; [2; 3; 4]; [3; 4; 5]]
```

for M = 3.

I know an imperative way of doing it, but is there a concise functional trick to do it?

Comment: Your example is overlapping sublists, not contiguous.

Comment: @Daniel: The sublists must be contiguous fragments of the input, so [1; 3; 4] is not allowed. If this is over-specified, let me know.

Comment: @Daniel: I added "overlapping" - it makes the description much clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a built-in function for this: [`Seq.windowed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340420.aspx)

Comment: Beautiful, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: that's just too easy. it must be illegal.